# Head tags inside body?

Tags: html, padding

I have strange issue(you can see problem only with firebug)
[Page without head tags inside body](http://staging.redcoats.co.uk)
and  [Page with head tags inside body](http://staging.redcoats.co.uk/dining-at-redcoats/)
This give me padding on same pages, while on other not.What is the cause of that behaviour?How to fix that?
tnx

Comment: Putting HEAD tags inside BODY is invalid.

Comment: you just killed an html fairy :-( and the space is it's dead body

Answer (score 6):

Head tags don't belong inside of body tags.  They should be removed.

Answer (score 0):

You have a carriage return before your doctype, in the second link.

It break the standard defined, and a fallback is used instead.

Comment: Yes : removing this carriage return =)

Comment: You have a new line in your document, just before the <!DOCTYPE>. Remove it.

Comment: I also think that might be problem, but no line before doctype.If you see pages in view source, yes,its display empty line..
what is going on, Im wondering??Frustrating :-)