# What to do with css for JSP fragment?

Tags: jsp, fragment, segment, jsp-fragments

I'm writing my first dynamic webpage with JSP. Right now I've got a working `index.JSP` without a header. I wrote a `header.jspf` which looks like this:

```
<header>
<div id="head">
<img src="images/header/logo.png" alt="logo">
<h1>Rewards</h1>
</div>
</header>
```

I included the header in my index.JSP with this line:  `<%@ include file="header.jspf" %>`, right after the body. But now I'm wondering. Where should I place the css for that header. I can put it inside the `header.JSPF`, but if I do that it get's inserted into the body when the page is 'built' by the server. I can place it in the `<head>` tag inside the `index.JSP` page, but then I should include the css every time I use that fragment.

Is there 'link' the css to `header.jspf` and everytime I include the header, the server automatically knows it should include that css for the header, without me typing everytime in my jsp, that I need that css file for the header?

==================================================================================

EDIT:
@San Krish

My header.jspf will look like this, I guess if, I include my css:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="cssFiles/header.css">
<header>
<div id="head">
<img src="images/header/logo.png" alt="logo">
<h1>Rewards</h1>
</div>
</header>
```

The problem however is that when I do that, the `<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="cssFiles/header.css">` gets inserted into the `body` of my `index.jsp` and that isn't valid HTML.

==================================================================================

EDIT2:
I've deleted the jspf and created a header.jsp file which looks like this (I copied all the content, I don't know if it is complete)

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>

<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="cssFiles/header.css">
</head>

<body>
<div id="head">
<img id="logo" src="images/header/logo.png" alt="logo">
<h1>Reward</h1>
</div>
</body>
```

Then instead of including the jspf in the index page I've done : `<%@ include file="header.jsp" %>`
The css however is still included inside the body :(.

Comment: Anyone an idea, how I can fix this, so my stylesheet isn't included  in my body (I want to keep the stylesheet with my header and not everytime manually import it when I include the header)

Comment: Does anyones has a clue? Maybe not the solution, but something that helps me finding the solution.

Comment: I'm starting a bounty, please also read the chat I wrote in San Krish answer.

Comment: may I ask, why do you need a valid html?

Comment: I just don't like it that there is a head inside my body. It makes no sense at all, it doesn't belong there. (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7000622/head-tags-inside-body)

Answer (score 1):

> Is there 'link' the css to header.jspf and everytime I include the
>   header, the server automatically knows it should include that css for
>   the header

`jspf` files are not compiled on their own so it needs to be executed with other jsp files.

You can include the common `css` and `js` files in the `common.jsp` so that all other files which uses `header.jspf` will lose the burden of linking the common `css` and `js` files.

**Update:**

> I've deleted the jspf and created a header.jsp file ,Then instead of
>   including the jspf in the index page I've done : <%@ include
>   file="header.jsp"  %> The css however is still included inside the
>   body

You have included the `header.jsp` with the css in the `index.jsp` , it is like emebedding the html page into another html page like below,

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
    <!-- when the app server interprets the jsp you have included it simply interprets like below -->
    <html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="cssFiles/header.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div id="head">
        <img id="logo" src="images/header/logo.png" alt="logo">
            <h1>Reward</h1>
    </div>
</body>
<html>
<h1>Content of the index page</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

*jsp's contains precompiled java code other than that it is similar to html, so you need not worry where it will place the css files (it is the work of browsers to render the external CSS into the head tag and it will happen normal)*

An extract from docs,

> The jsp:include action inserts additional static or dynamic resources
>   into the page at request time as the page is displayed. Specify the
>   resource with a relative URL (either page-relative or
>   application-relative).

**Learn More :**

- [Startup tutorial for java-ee](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/servlet-138661.html)
- [Understanding Web Applications, Servlets, and JSPs](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E21764_01/web.1111/e13712/basics.htm#WBAPP118)
- [jsp:include](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/A87860_01/doc/java.817/a83726/genlovw3.htm)

Comment: First of all, Thank you. I've edited my question. Please have a look.

Comment: Pls check my update . you can all have the common files in the jsp and include it in the normal way .so that when your `.jspf` file can get the required css

Comment: I understand that I have to include the jspf in my jsp. But When I define the css stylesheet inside my jspf and let the server 'build' the index.jsp, the css stylesheet is included inside the BODY.

Comment: Yes you are right as the jspf files are not compiled in before hand , it just populate the values in the body .So better create a separate jsp which contains link to all css and js and include it in the jsp pages you use

Comment: No sorry, I don't understna dit, So I would have to create a new JSP file, whith <head><body> etc, that includes the jspf. And after that I should Include the new jsp files (that already contains a head body etc) ito another jsp?

Comment: It is enough to create it with head alone . with all imports for the css . For ex, name it as common.jsp and include common.jsp in all your jsp pages

Comment: It didn't work, can you tell what I've done wrong please (I've edited my question.)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/64410/discussion-between-san-krish-and-user2815780).

Comment: @Bosiwow Check my update , hope it makes it clear. Also edited the header.jsp in the way it should be .

Comment: Will have a look at it tomorrow, but I'll give you the bounty now.